# agm-map on a non-active ngb-tab using fitbounds with GeoJson

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-google-maps, agm

I'm trying to get an `agm-map` to show on a second tab of an `ngb-tabset`, and to `fitbounds` around the geojson that gets loaded.

Here is a stackblitz with the map on the first tab - it works fine, apart from maybe the first load, when 'google is undefined'. (I would normally load the geojson data from an API based on user input, so the google maps script would have loaded by then.)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-6ynh9n

If you uncomment the other (first) `ngb-tab` in the html, then it all goes to pot: now the `ViewChild` (this.agmMap) is undefined in `ngAfterViewInit`. If you can get around that (by using something like `(tabChange)="tabChanged($event)"`, then when you click away from the map tab, then back to it, the map doesn't fitbounds to the geojson as the map has been destroyed and recreated; agmMap doesn't get re-initialised either (`mapReady`).

(I also can't get the agmMap's fitbounds to work, so I'm using the GoogleMap's fitbounds directly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, this is a known [issue](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1562). The workaround is to lazy load the tab.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone looking for a working example, see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-maps-tab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts